# After creating SQS message, how can I monitor when it gets deleted?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

My program creates a message in a SQS queue and then needs to wait for one of the workers pulling work on the queue to process it.  I want to monitor the status of a message to determine when it gets deleted, since that would be my indicator that the work is done.  But I can't figure out a way to do this with the SQS API.

```
SendMessageRequest msgRequest = new SendMessageRequest(SQS_QUEUE_URL, messageBody);
SendMessageResult result = sqsClient.sendMessage(msgRequest);

String msgId = result.getMessageId();

// so, in theory, this is what I WANT to do...

while(!sqsClient.wasThisMessageDeletedYet(msgId))
   Thread.sleep(1000L);

// continue, confident that because the message was deleted, I can rely upon the fact that the result of the Worker is now stashed where it's supposed to be
```

What's the right way to do "wasThisMessageDeletedYet(id)"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid such an API endpoint doesn't exist; looking at the API reference (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), you could see that there are no methods for querying messages.

Maybe you could try with "change message visibility", but that:

- has side effects
- you would need to know the receipt handle which you obtain when receiving the message

So I suppose your best bet is to store that state in some external database (if you want to stay in Amazon-land, maybe Dynamo?). With a simple message id -> boolean mapping indicating if messages have been processed or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get away from using a db because the number of connections needed to poll gets quickly out of control.  

When a worker finishes his work, I think the best way for the sender to become aware of that fact is to... 

a) workers put the finished msg id's into memcached, 
b) senders create SNS topics for each msg and subscribes; when a Worker does his thing, he puts a "done" msg on the SNS topic, then the sender deletes the topic.  But I'm not sure about the performance overhead of creating and destroying SNS topics for every message.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another option (but similar) is for the consumer to publish the status in a response queue. The wait will have to be done asynchronously (a Future perhaps).

Obviously there an overhead in processing as well as complexity in programming due to the asynchronous nature of interactions. But typically it is done this way.